# Begineer: first program for Circular Singly Linked List,

Tags: c++, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

Its returning an address only , without any debugger errors although my both DEV C++ and Code::Blocks compiler are showing send dont send windows errors but they initalize the class object only, I have included the code , can anyone tell me why its happening

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *nextptr;
};


class CLLIST{

private:

     Node*firstptr;
     Node*lastptr;

public:
     CLLIST(){

     cout << "Constructor Called !";
      firstptr=lastptr=NULL;
}

void insert_at_back(int val){

         if(firstptr==NULL) //it means start of C.LIST
         {
             Node*temptr = new Node; //means firstptr = temptr
             firstptr->data=val;
             firstptr=temptr;
             firstptr->nextptr=firstptr;
         } else{

             Node*temp1 = new Node;
             Node*temp2 = new Node;

             temp1 = firstptr;
             while(temp1->nextptr!=firstptr) //traversing
             {
                 temp2 = temp1->nextptr;
                 temp2->data = val; //inserted at back
                 temp2->nextptr=firstptr; //circle completed
             }
         }
}

void printit(){

           // functiont o print all the circular link lists data
           Node*temp3ptr= new Node;
           temp3ptr = firstptr;

           while(temp3ptr->nextptr!=firstptr)//traversing
           {
              cout << temp3ptr->data;
              cout << endl;
           }
}
};


  int main()
  {
    CLLIST obj1;

    obj1.insert_at_back(10);
    obj1.insert_at_back(20);
    obj1.insert_at_back(30);

    obj1.printit();

    cout << "Done !";

    getch();
  }
```

Comment: Node*temptr = new Node; //means firstptr = temptr
             firstptr->data=val;

Comment: firstptr is still = NULL at that point

Answer (score 3):

A few issues with your current code (there may be more, but you should focus on resolving these first)

---

**Issue 1**:

```
         if(firstptr==NULL) //it means start of C.LIST
         {
             Node*temptr = new Node; //means firstptr = temptr
             firstptr->data=val;
             firstptr=temptr;
             firstptr->nextptr=firstptr;
         } else{
```

^ With `firstptr->data=val;` you are dereferencing `firstptr` even though it's still `NULL`. Swap it and the next line so it reads:

```
         if(firstptr==NULL) //it means start of C.LIST
         {
             Node*temptr = new Node; //means firstptr = temptr
             firstptr=temptr;
             firstptr->data=val;
             firstptr->nextptr=firstptr;
         } else{
```

Or better yet just do: `firstptr = new Node;` directly and skip the `temptr`

---

**Issue 2**:

```
     Node*temp1 = new Node;
     Node*temp2 = new Node;

     temp1 = firstptr;
     while(temp1->nextptr!=firstptr) //traversing
     {
         temp2 = temp1->nextptr;
         temp2->data = val; //inserted at back
         temp2->nextptr=firstptr; //circle completed
     }
```

^ This is a memory leak; `new` allocates memory for them on the heap, whose addresses are lost when you assign the temp Nodes to point to `firstptr`. Just declare `temp1` and `temp2` instead:

```
     Node*temp1;
     Node*temp2;
```

---

**Issue 3**:

```
    while(temp1->nextptr!=firstptr)
```

^ this while-loop will never run because:

- You start with `firstptr` as null
- Then you add a node, and `firstptr->next` points back to `firstptr`.
- Then when you tried to add a 2nd node, it does the work of assigning `temp1 = firstptr;`, but the while loop is not run because `firstptr->next == firstptr`

---

**Issue 4**:

As @aleguna pointed out:

```
       Node*temp3ptr= new Node;
       temp3ptr = firstptr;
```

^ This is another memory leak, for the same reason as stated in Issue 2. Just declare `temp3ptr` instead:

```
       Node*temp3ptr;
```

---

**Issue 5**:

```
       while(temp3ptr->nextptr!=firstptr)//traversing
       {
          cout << temp3ptr->data;
          cout << endl;
       }
```

^ Here you need a way to actually iterate through your circularly linked list, right now it's just printing the 1st node repeatedly (well, technically the other parts of your code doesn't let you add a 2nd node into the linked list yet, either)

Something like:

```
       while(temp3ptr->nextptr!=firstptr)//traversing
       {
          cout << temp3ptr->data;
          cout << endl;
          // Can technically do it without the if-check since this
          // is circular, but better to code defensively.
          if (temp3ptr->next != NULL) {
              temp3ptr = temp3ptr->next;
          }
       }
```

Comment: there is another leak in `printit`: `temp3ptr = firstptr;`

Comment: Hmm.. It means that if i want to assign firstptr the address , i have to use    firstptr = new Node;

similarly it means that i also made the same mistake in the insert_at_back function ?

Comment: thank you very much,, i am editng the code to make it run,,, if i will face any problem i will ask again.

Comment: I can't figure out how should i obtain the end of the node if my loop is not running ?

any hint ?

Comment: @aleguna how should i give the temp3ptr than address of firstptr because i wanto to traverse through the list ?

Comment: @sampson-chen Please can you tell me how should i add a new node at the end ?